# BIO_do_connect() fails seemingly because SSL v3 is used, is there a way to get more diagnostics?

Tags: c++, ssl, paypal, openssl

I wrote a class to handle SSL connections that I use to communicate with Paypal.

It worked just fine for about a year and now it fails right away. From the error I get, it would seem that this happens because they (finally) turned off the SSLv3 cipher. Yet, I thought it was turned off on my end already.

There is the error I get when attempting my connection with my code:

> 139673112286976:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40

I get the exact same error if I try to connect with `-ssl3` using the command line tool:

```
openssl s_client -connect api.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -ssl3
```

Note that the command line without the `-ssl3` option works as expected.

And I have seen a couple of posts that say that the error means there is a problem with the cipher used, leading me to think that is the problem I'm running into.

For those interested, the whole class is found in our [snapcpp git](https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/tcp_client_server.cpp) (go up one to get the .h and other files from the snapwebsites library).

There is the relevant code. I removed the error checking happening before the one that triggers the current failure:

```
std::shared_ptr<SSL_CTX> ssl_ctx(SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method()), ssl_ctx_deleter);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ssl_ctx.get(), 4);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx.get(), SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ssl_ctx.get(), "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4");
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx.get(), NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs");
std::shared_ptr<BIO> bio(BIO_new_ssl_connect(ssl_ctx.get()), bio_deleter);
SSL * ssl(nullptr);
BIO_get_ssl(bio.get(), &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio.get(), const_cast<char *>(addr.c_str()));
BIO_set_conn_int_port(bio.get(), &port);
if(BIO_do_connect(bio.get()) <= 0)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    throw tcp_client_server_initialization_error("failed connecting BIO object to server");
}
```

So my class throws because the BIO_do_connect() gets the error I mentioned earlier. Yet I would think that these options:

```
SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
```

would be enough to avoid SSLv3.

What else could be the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1` yet you use TLSv1 method.

Try changing `TLSv1_client_method()` to `SSLv23_client_method()`. This will alow usage of any method (in fact it will negotiate the highest available SSL/TLS version). You can limit it with `SSL_CTX_set_options` as you did in your code.

For some reasons the documentation says that `SSLv23_method()` is deprecated and one should use `TLS_method()`. Howerer, there isn't such thing in their newest (OpenSSL 1.0.2e) code.

Comment: About the `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1`, I looked at the header file and I could see that there are `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1` and `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2` macros too. So I assumed that the TLSv1 by itself meant version 1.0 which is pretty close to SSL 3 and thus should not be used either...

Comment: In any event, just changing the `TLSv1_client_method()` to `SSLv23_client_method()` did the trick. Rather confusing! But I got right in once I did that one small change.